# Looking for an magento quicklook extension as in www.myntra.com

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

[image]I am looking for a quick buy/quick-look/ quick-view extension for my website with same functionality for the quick look module in www.myntra.com.

[image]

So far My quick-view uses fancy-box module. Which is entirely different from myntra.com. I am looking for an basic idea to achieve the above quick-look extension.
Even google uses the same concept for their Image search.Please take a look at this.[image]

Comment: Now can you guys get me an solution??

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to create one...as you liked...
you can also get online if you search in google..
I also created one...for my site...
Basically you have to customized one...
i m giving you link of some paid and free...

### paid

http://magento-quickview.cmsideas.net/index.php/apparel/shirts.html
http://www.extendware.com/magento-quick-view.html
https://amasty.com/magento-quick-view.html

### Free

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quickview-1-7580.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quickview-1-7580.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/em-quick-shop-quick-view-product.html

and also u can get many more if u search on google

Comment: Thank you Deepak.I have used those free extensions but they are either in light-box or fancy-box module. I want to know what myntra uses for its quickview. It is similar to google image search. I am really confused.

Comment: basically myntra ...is one core php...they using slider ...and they placed the product on that...and on next and previous button ...they use product id .....you can also use incho prev next extension for that....but you have to customize that.....   http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-products/listing-out-previousnext-products-in-magento-inchoo_prevnext-extension/

Comment: Can you suggest me what view mode they are using in product grid for Quick view? Eg., Light-Box, Fancy-Box...

Comment: they using java script core may be but you can also use facnybox pop slider...you can check myntra technology  here http://builtwith.com/myntra.com

Comment: Finally I got an clue to start with. https://github.com/codrops/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview